# SPFx webpart with @pnp/spfx and Angular elements not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp

I have created SPFx webpart for Angular Elements using below link:

https://pnp.github.io/generator-spfx/howtos/angularelements/

Getting error in **npm run bundle** as below:

[image]

Comment: This error is because it is unable to find the `runtime.js` file at specified location? is it checking at wrong path or you misplaced this file?

Comment: So how can i identify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this generator In June and I got bundle error and did research&test, and update the es target to es5 and got bundle successed.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

If you can't bundle successfully, I suggest you post in github https://github.com/pnp/generator-spfx/issues